# Как выполнить python-скрипт по расписанию,в Виндовс?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, командная-строка

Есть два файла. **Main.py** и **send_message.py**.

В файле main указывается время,в которое надо выполнить send_message.
Как это сделать в Windows?

Comment: Возможно данная статья поможет https://datatofish.com/python-script-windows-scheduler/ в ней приводится пример запуск Python скрипта стандартными методами планировщика в Windows

Answer (score 1):

используй планировщик задач:

"настройки"-"панель управления" - "администрирование" - "планировщик задач"

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
def sleeper(delay):
    time.sleep(delay)
    your_function()
```

И используйте расширение файлов `.pyw`. Оно для `Windows` позволит запустить скрипт на `Python` без открытия консоли. Но если ваша функция `send_message` содержит что-то вроде `print()` и `input()`, лучше обернуть её в локальный импорт и `systemcall`.